# how can i set npm build option? I want to put my css and js file in static folder. (vue cli 3,npm, vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm using `vue cli 3`, `Vuetify`. My back-end programmer asked me that put my `css`, `js`, and img file in static folder for him. How can I do? I cannot find `webpack.config.js` file at `vue cli 3`. some guys said use `vue.config.js` file, but I still don't know how to solve this problem.
thank you.

this link is build result. I want to put css, img, js files in one static folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Public Folder for Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder). To quote the docs

> Any static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths.

All you would need to do is place your css, js, images in your `public` folder